# Get each array into an SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, file, foreach

**Problem:**

Getting each array generated from a text file into an SQL query. I have a text file containing this type of lines of airport information: https://abc-supervisor.c9users.io/airports.txt

If you do not wish to click the link, here's a sample:

```
1,"Goroka","Goroka","Papua New Guinea","GKA","AYGA",-6.081689,145.391881,5282,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby"
2,"Madang","Madang","Papua New Guinea","MAG","AYMD",-5.207083,145.7887,20,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby"
3,"Mount Hagen","Mount Hagen","Papua New Guinea","HGU","AYMH",-5.826789,144.295861,5388,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby"
```

I'm trying to get each value into a SQL table.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    $lines = file('airports.txt');

    echo '<xmp>';

    $airport = array();

    foreach($lines as $row) 
    {
      $airport = str_replace('"', '', explode(",", $row));
      print_r($airport);
    }

    echo '</xmp>';
?>
```

**Outputs:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => Goroka
    [2] => Goroka
    [3] => Papua New Guinea
    [4] => GKA
    [5] => AYGA
    [6] => -6.081689
    [7] => 145.391881
    [8] => 5282
    [9] => 10
    [10] => U
    [11] => Pacific/Port_Moresby

)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => Madang
    [2] => Madang
    [3] => Papua New Guinea
    [4] => MAG
    [5] => AYMD
    [6] => -5.207083
    [7] => 145.7887
    [8] => 20
    [9] => 10
    [10] => U
    [11] => Pacific/Port_Moresby

)
```

**Desired output:**

Insert each value into a row in SQL. Thankful if someone could point in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you want to read the CSV file in and load each line to a row of a database table.

The easiest way you be to use LOAD DATA INFILE, if the file is accessible to the MySQL server. Something like this (not tested and not something I use often)

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$mysqli->query("LOAD DATA INFILE 'airports.txt' 
                INTO TABLE expenses  
                    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
                           OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                    LINES  TERMINATED BY '\\n' 
                (col0, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11)");
```

but assuming you might want to do some other processing on some of the values before hand, or the file is not accessible from MySQL then you might want to just do an insert of each line manually (note that you could insert multiple rows at once which would be far more efficient, but that is a separate question).

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

if (($handle = fopen('airports.txt', "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO some_table(col0, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")) {
            $stmt->bind_param("isssssddiiss", $data[0], $data[1], $data[2], $data[3], $data[4], $data[5], $data[6], $data[7], $data[8], $data[9], $data[10], $data[11]);
            $stmt->execute();
        }   
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but unfortunately none of the solutions work on Cloud9.

Comment: What is cloud9? Some kind of cloud storage? Do you have a separate cloud storage containing this file and a different server with the scripts on it?

Comment: I immediately regret my words, it worked fine. Just had to modify the code for PDO. Wasn't paying attention that you used mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

json encode it store in database

```
foreach($lines as $row) 
{
  $airport = str_replace('"', '', explode(",", $row));
  $json = json_encode($airport );
  //Code to store $json in database
}
```

When you retrieve the data you can use json_decode to decode it.

```
if you want to store field wise you can do this

    foreach ($airport as $key => $field) { 
      for($i=0;$i<11;$i++){
       if($key == 'i') {
         $value[$i] = $field; }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table name (fields1,fields2,...) values ($value[0],$value[1]...); }
```

Comment: But what if he wants to do queries on each field individually ? this can't be done when storing the array as a json object.

Comment: Once you store the value in database, later you can decode the value and do whatever stuff you want. His query was simple, he just want to store that data in database.

Comment: @teeyo This is exactly what I am looking for. Sorry if I was not being clear about this.

Comment: @kexxcream did you try the second solution?

Comment: @AmitRay I just did and only the first letter is outputted when you echo $value[0] or $value[1].

Comment: @kexxcream Each field should have different types. like id stored as int(11), name stored as varchar(255) etc. Can you paste your table structure here?

Comment: That's not the issue, if you try to print out the values in PHP you will see the issue.

Comment: I have changed the code. Sincere Apology. Kindly recheck it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112262/discussion-between-amit-ray-and-kexxcream).

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach ($airport as $key => $value)
   {
     $sql = "INSERT INTO table name (fields1,fields2,...) values    ($value[0],$value[1]...)
   }
```

Comment: This does not work, I tried to output the different values first before entering them and it only output the first letter for each key.

Comment: whats the problem this code foreach ($airport as $value) { 
$sql = "INSERT INTO table name (fields1,fields2,...) values ($value[0],$value[1]...) }

Comment: Only the first letter of each value is displayed.

Comment: you mean $value get only first letter